# CentOS DHCP server failover won't give out leases

Tags: centos, dhcp, failover

I have followed this tutorial: http://www.madboa.com/geek/dhcp-failover/

However, I can not seem to get a lease at my windows client.

I have set both servers (CentOS 6.2) in virtual machines, connected by the same LAN segment. (with VMWare Workstation).

My Windows client is also a virtual machine in the same network segment.
If I, as in the tutorial, made a single DHCP server, I was able to get a lease. But now that I have two DHCP servers, connected with the failover protocol, I can't seem to get the lease.

I have no idea where the problem could be. I have already synced both servers with the `ntpdate` command, giving them the same time and date (so there is no time difference).

The log from the secondary server gives me `peer holds all free leases` and the log from the master gives me `not responding (recovering)`.

I can ping from master to slave and slave to master, but I can not ping from the Windows client to either the master or the slave. If I do so, I get this:

> PING: transmit failed, error 1231.
>
> PING: transmit failed, error 1231.

Please tell me whatever other relevant info I should give.

Comment: Try: disable firewall on both (`sudo /etc/init.d/iptables stop`), disable SELinux (`sudo setenforce 0`) and restart DHCPd on both. Also, it would be useful to check `less /var/log/messages`

Comment: Didn't do the trick, I still can't get a lease. The less /var/log/messages give me basicly the same as the regular log, saying 'not responding (recovering)' and the secondary 'peer holds all free leases'

Comment: Actually, I think it did work,, I was reading some more documentation, came back to my virtual machine and there was a different log, which enabled me to debug and get it working, thanks @Chris !

Answer (score 1):

The error message `peer holds all free leases` can also mean that the request has been received on the wrong network interface, e.g. if a computer is only configured to get an IP on `eth0`, but the DHCP request is received on `eth1`. In my case one interface was for the workstation network and the other one for printers only and someone plugged a workstation into the printer network.

See [my blog posting about when I ran into that error message and found no obvious reason](http://noone.org/blog/English/Computer/peer%20holds%20all%20free%20leases.futile), too. (Ran into it on Debian, but that shouldn't make a difference.)

The again, I can't remember having seen the message `not responding (recovering)` anywhere, but instead I had `peer holds all free leases` on both DHCP servers.

I though can imagine that in this case maybe one of the two machines may have two interfaces mixed up with regards to the network they're connected to.